# If $x+y < z$, find $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x+y+\epsilon < z$ and $x + \epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x,y$ and $z$ be some real numbers such that $x + y < z$. I know it is possible to find $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x + y + \epsilon < z$. But is it possible to find $\epsilon$ such that in addition to that, $x+\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$? My gut feeling is "yes", but not sure how to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is irrational then it is clearly impossible, because $\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$ implies $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I agree with that but I have a question.
Suppose you have $x$ irrational such that $x = 1.4145...$, you can pick $y = 0.5854..$ such that $x + y = 1.9999...$.
$x$ and $y$ might be irrational, but in this case, $x + y$ is rational, right ?

Comment: If you are asking whether the sum of two irrational numbers can be rational, then the answer is yes.

Comment: cool, thanks. I didn't notice the $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$